# Run PHP script from command line and max_execution_time

Tags: php, linux

if you run a PHP script from the command line is the `max_execution_time` then unlimited?

```
# php php_script.php
```

Comment: You could always try it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

See http://php.net/cli and there specifically http://php.net/commandline.differences